# Double pointers Android JNI

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface, native

I have a function that gets a double pointer

```
int getList(unsigned char **list); //it returns a list of something
```

I would like to know how to pass a double pointer from native code (JNI) to my function. Anyone?

this is what I've tried but it doesn't work.

```
jint Java_test_test_Activity_getList(JNIEnv *env, jobject this, jobjectArray list, jint size){
   jint count=0;
   jbyteArray bArray;
   jByteArray cList;
   count=(*env)->GetArrayLength(env, list);
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++){
       bArray[i]=(*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, list, i);
       (*env)->GetByteArrayRegion(env, bArray[i], 0, size, cList[i]);
     }

    return  getList(cList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can't you use the '&' operator to get the adress ofyour jByteArray?

```
return  getList(&cList);
```

'&' in C/C++ give you the address of a variable (a pointer). You can use it on a pointer to get a double pointer.
But I'm not sure that the cast between jByteArray and unsigned char* is that simple, you might have something else to do.

Comment: Unlikely, unless the Android native interface is quite different from Java's... to get a pointer to memory within the JVM you need to pin/lock the memory first.

Answer (score 0):

Double pointers are generally not such a big deal. You just have to keep all 3 layers in mind.

1. The layer where you can directly access the value of a variable. (e.g. int a; a = 3;)
2. This layer will keep a pointer to your previously defined variable.
   (e.g. int *p = &a;)
3. The last layer is where a pointer points to another pointer. (e.g. int *p2 = &p)

So let's assume we are on level 3 and we are using the pointer p2.

1. *p2 will give us the pointer p.
2. now we just need to dereference p to get to a, so *p will give us the value of a.

So in order to keep a double pointer of something you need to return the pointer of the lowest layer. (e.g (&(&a)))

And in order to get to the value you need to dereference twice, as mentioned. (e.g. *(*ptr) )

Why are you trying to store a jobjectArray element into a jByteArray element?

```
bArray[i]=(*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, list, i);
```

Besides, instead of jByteArray cList you could directly use the C/C++ equivalent, but this probably isn't relevant for fixing your error.